# how can i connect to oracle database with python?

Tags: database, oracle, connection, timeout

When I run the command:

`"connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pw, dsn, encoding='utf8')"`,

then I got the error:

```
"ORA-12170: TNS: Connect timeout occurred."
```

For additional information; on my tablet, first I connected to a non static ip address;  then connected to my desktop remotely that has a static Ip address. I am working on my remote desktop with all the programs included (oracle, python, etc.)

Comment: Make sure connectivity is in place by utilizing netcat: nc -vz mydbhostname 1521. After successful output, go on with python.